# How to set up openstack local.conf for Mitaka in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, devstack

I installed Openstack Mitaka using devstack for many times and there were always some bugs. I think it has something to do with the initial network set up.

For virtual box, I added a new host-only network "vboxnet0" with configures:

> IPv4:192.168.56.1
>
> IPv4 network mask: 255.255.255.0
>
> Disable DHCP server (the NAT network enabled DHCP)

And for the virtual machine I created, I used Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop, with network configures:

> Adapter 1: NAT
>
> Adapter 2: Host-only adapter - vboxnet0.

Then after virtual machine initialisation and basic update, I got:

```
>>ifconfig
lo - 127.0.0., Mask: 255.0.0.0, scope: host
eth0 - 10.0.2.15, Mask: 255.255.255.0, scope: link
eth1 - 0.0.0.1., Mask: 0.0.0.0, scope: link
```

So how should I set the devstack/local.conf file? I tried to install devstack without setting it but after I created an instance, I could't console into the instance. And also the instance got an IP like `174.24.4.x`, which is quite weird because I thought it should be something like `10.0.0.x`.

Comment: I went through your same problems. Firstly, don't use Ubuntu Desktop, go with Ubuntu Server. I was having some issues as well, so in the end I started using CentOS, much better, and specially after many other issues

Comment: @vabada Thanks for you reply. Have you managed to set up the whole environment successfully? Like create an instance and use this instance to access outside internet? I managed to create an instance but this instance cannot access outside net.

Comment: Not with Ubuntu server. The last issue I had was after having it launched: neither could I open the console in the Horizon interface nor could establish an SSH connection. With CentOS everything is working fine

Comment: @vabada did you deploy Openstack on CentOS with Devstack?

Comment: oh sorry. Obviously not. I used packstack, which is the equivalent to Devstack for CentOS

Comment: @vabada thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was struggling to install Openstack on virtual box.

Then I configured virtual box as given in this website https://linuxhint.com/install_openstack_virtualbox/ and then things worked fine.

I used linux server though.

Let me know if you still get any specific error, I have seen a lot of errors and can help you